# Laravel Give a remark notice to a specific user from admin

Tags: laravel, eloquent

(Im rather new to laravel but ill try to explain my problem as best as I can)
I'm trying to create a remark application that should be simple enough, where the admin can pass some data to a specific user and the user can see the data on a table from their own dashboard.

So I thought I should show all the users in one table then from a button or text i can click to create a "remark notice" and it would choose that user based on their id and then store it on a table
I have already made a foreign key with the two tables Notice at the recieverID with the ID of the Users table
This is how the table with all the users look
[this is how all users look and the button to access the create function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQYmb.png)

Then it shows the create view of the remark
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKbxb.png)

Here I made it so it gets the id on the link of the specific user
[url with specific id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQqeL.png)

This is the code that I am using for this(RemarkController)

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::all();
    return view('admin.remark.index', compact('users'));
} 
 public function create()
{   
    // $user = User::find($id);      
    return view('admin.remark.create', compact('user'));
}
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'title'=>'required',
        'subject'=>'required',
        'message'=>'required',
        'sender'=>'required'
        ]);
        $data=$request->all();
        $data['recieverID']=auth()->user()->id;
        Remark::create($data);
        return redirect()->route('remarks')->with('message','Remark Created Successfully');    }
```

And this is how I use the code to show the id of the selected user on the link and i was thinking because of this it would store on the table

```
<td><a href="{{route('remarks.create', $user->id)}}"><i class="fa fa-edit" style="font-size:20px; color: #e03e27;"></i></a></td>
```

But instead, I get an error like this

> ErrorException Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

I'm not sure what to do since I'm a beginner and I would really appreciate your help thank you
EDIT: Error picture
[error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QROS6.png)

Comment: In `create` function you user is commented. Is that right?

Comment: Yes i commented that because it gets an error I was also just testing it to see if it did something else

Comment: Screen capture of url with id shows `create?248` you are not passing the id here. I suspect it's a problem with your route. Share your route maybe?

Comment: The route on the view is this 
`<form method="POST" action="{{route('remarks.store')}}">` 

and in the web routing its just 
`Route::resource('remarks','RemarkController');`

Comment: create method on resource route will not accept a parameter. You need to create a new route that would accept a parameter. Also create method needs to accept the id, or as someone else commented, the User model to bind

Comment: This is what it shows when i add the id parameter to the create method
`Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\RemarkController::create(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, my suggestion is to exclude create method when you create the resource route.

```
Route::resource('remarks','RemarkController', [
    'except' => ['create']
]);
```

Make a new route for create like so:

```
Route::get('remarks/create/{user}', 'RemarkController@create')->name('remarks.create');
```

And then change your create method to implicitly bind user:

```
public function create(User $user)
{   
    return view('admin.remark.create', compact('user'));
}
```

**EDIT:**
As for store method, I understand from your comments that the `data['receiverId']` should be the `id` of the `user` sent to create method / user id in the create link. I suggest you post this id in a hidden field in your form. So, include a new hidden field in the create form:

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{$user->id}}" name="receiverId" />
```

This way you can get rid of the `$data['receiverId']` line, because you are sending that along with other form data.

Edit 3: removed post/redirect bit since it looks like it was a misreading on my part.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you try to find the user by the id, but the create() function doesn't have it as a parameter. So the correct way should be:

```
public function create($id)
{   
    $user = User::find($id);      
    return view('admin.remark.create', compact('user'));
}
```

Comment: And you could also use Route-Model binding like ```public function create(User $id)```

Comment: It returned 
`Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\RemarkController::create(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected`

Comment: I assumed that you send the id as a route parameter.

Answer (score -1):

As the error says, you're trying to get the property `id` with an object accessor `->`, while $user isn't an object. Try to dump the user with `dd($user)` and check, what you get. If you get an array, you'd need to use `[]` to access it.

Comment: What is a dd at the dd($user) should I change it with something else or just use it like that?

Comment: This is completely off, imo.